# Explain statsmodels's detrend function

Tags: time-series, trend, statsmodels

Can someone help me to understand what is the detrend function from python's statsmodels? Or provide some reference to this method? Especially when set order= 1, 2, ... to 5. I have pasted the source code as below.

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.tsatools.detrend.html

```
def detrend(x, order=1, axis=0):
    """
    Detrend an array with a trend of given order along axis 0 or 1

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like, 1d or 2d
        data, if 2d, then each row or column is independently detrended with the
        same trendorder, but independent trend estimates
    order : int
        specifies the polynomial order of the trend, zero is constant, one is
        linear trend, two is quadratic trend
    axis : int
        axis can be either 0, observations by rows,
        or 1, observations by columns

    Returns
    -------
    detrended data series : ndarray
        The detrended series is the residual of the linear regression of the
        data on the trend of given order.
    """
    if x.ndim == 2 and int(axis) == 1:
        x = x.T
    elif x.ndim > 2:
        raise NotImplementedError('x.ndim > 2 is not implemented until it is needed')

    nobs = x.shape[0]
    if order == 0:
        # Special case demean
        resid = x - x.mean(axis=0)
    else:
        trends = np.vander(np.arange(float(nobs)), N=order + 1)
        beta = np.linalg.pinv(trends).dot(x)
        resid = x - np.dot(trends, beta)

    if x.ndim == 2 and int(axis) == 1:
        resid = resid.T

    return resid
```

Comment: Hi Lisa, wlecome to CrossValidated!! It looks like this code fits a polynomial of order `order` to the data you feed into the function and returns the residuals.
 
Exactly which lines in this code are unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it fits a polynomial regression, with an order p, i.e. linear regression where the the x variable is expanded so

p=1: Y ~ x

p=2: Y ~ x + x^2

p=3: Y ~ x + x^2 + x^3

etc.

and return residuals. Thus if there is some linear or nonlinear trend in the data, it will be removed